# Change indicator in AjaxLazyLoadPanel

Tags: wicket

How can I change the indicator that is shown when loading a AjaxLazyLoadPanel?
I tried to override the `getLoadingComponent` and implementing `IAjaxIndicatorAware` in the Panel I return from the `AjaxLazyLoadPanel`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overriding `getLoadingComponent(String)` is the correct way!

See the default impl at https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/e4ea6d7b488f04948fd50b69e06da2d231e3b5ba/wicket-extensions/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/extensions/ajax/markup/html/AjaxLazyLoadPanel.java#L134

Just return another Component that renders what you want to render.

Or show us your code so we can tell you what is not OK.

Comment: Yes did this works, but I needed to return a Label instead of WebMarkupContainer.

Comment: @greesin, wrapping your Label into a Panel should just work fine. Then just return the Panel at getLoadingComponent(String).